# UICollectionView adding action in Header to imageview

Tags: header, action, collectionview

Adding the tap gesture to the imageView present above the header and not getting inside the action

```
   let headerTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "headerClicked")
   headerTap.delegate = self
   headerTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
   headerTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
   image.addGestureRecognizer(headerTap)
```

Comment: We can create a UIView above the header view and add the tap gesture to it . working properly for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIButton instead of UIImageView it will reduce the tap gesture code I think.

Comment: but that my images are not of same size so i want to use the image view onl

Comment: Any way you can control the size of button like imageView.